# Bash: expand variables (including compound expressions) without executing the main commands

Tags: bash

I have a file that contains the output of a makefile execution. Some of its line have complex expressions in it. For example, one of the lines could include some complex bash expression like:

```
gcc main.c -I$(if [ $A == "Val1" ]; then echo /usr/include; else echo /usr/local/include; fi)
```

The file could have thousand of lines. I want to know how could I tell bash: echo the result of evaluating each one of line of this file independently, without actually executing the commands.

Actually, there's only one two usages of `$`:

- To refer to `$A`, which is a variable that always exists.
- An embedded if as shown above: `$(if ...)`
- References to `$A` can happen inside `$(if ...)`s, and sometimes there's an `$(if ...)` inside another `$(if ...)`.
- The contents within each `if` must be evaluated in case there's calls to other commands (as far as I've found, the only command that I think is called inside such `if`s are calls to `echo`).

So I want bash to expand and call whatever command is required to resolve all `$` usages, but never execute the command represented by the line itself, but print the expanded result on the standard output instead.

How can I do that?

Comment: BTW, `[ $a == "Val1" ]` is buggy twice over. It should be `=` instead of `==` to comply with the [POSIX `test` spec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html), and the quotes [should be around `$a`](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2086); they're unnecessary around `Val1`.

Comment: That said, if you mean the result to generate code you can run that will have the same result as executing your original code, that's not actually going to happen. The results of parameter expansions and command substitutions only go through a subset of the parsing process -- globbing and word-splitting when the operation was unquoted, but nothing else. Failing to realize this is the underlying issue behind [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your an entire file in an unquoted heredoc. That is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
: "${A?Error: variable A must always exist before running this code}"
cat <<EOF
# ...put your entire file's contents here...
# ...including the line...
gcc main.c -I$(if [ $A == "Val1" ]; then echo /usr/include; else echo /usr/local/include; fi)
EOF
```

The contents will have expansions performed, but not otherwise be executed.

Comment: It works. Unbelievable.